# What is the force produced by the centre of a Solenoid on a permanent magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

I understand that the equation for the force produced by a solenoid is :$ F = \frac{(N*I)^2 * μ * A }{2x^2}  $ with; N number of coils, I current, μ permeability of free space, A cross sectional area, x distance from the solenoid.
However, I don't believe this applies to the point directly at its centre. Instead this relates to the equation for B field which is: $B=\frac{μNI}{L}$. How can I convert this Bfield calculation into one for Force when the solenoid is acting on a small cylindrical magnet?

Comment: There are no easy ways to calculate the force of a solenoid on a magnetic material. We have to solve the equations of magnetostatics for the geometry of the coil and the magnetic material, which are 3 dimensional non-linear partial differential equations. If the system has cylindrical symmetry the calculation becomes considerably easier. If all you need is the solution (rather than the theory of how to get the solution), then I would suggest to use a magnetic field solver software like Femm, which is about as easy to use as one can make it.